# Problems referencing functions in self in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on this code, but the startup function doesn't run. I recieve no errors. This is for a card game, help? I am using python 3 and running via command prompt on windows 10. For my text editor I am using Atom.

```
import random
print("Sam's Casino")

class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J',
        'Q','K','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J',
        'Q','K','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J',
        'Q','K','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J',
        'Q','K']
        self.hand1 = []
        self.hand2 = []
        self.center = []
        self.pile1 = []
        self.pile2 = []
        self.points1 = 0
        self.points2 = 0
        input('__init__ completed - ')
        self.startup(self)

    def deal(self):
        self.count = 0
        for card in self.cards:
            if self.count < 4:
                self.hand1.append(card)
                self.count += 1
            elif self.count > 3 and self.count < 8:
                self.hand2.append(card)
                self.count += 1
            print('hi')
            input('deal test - ')

    def startup(self):
        input('startup __init__ test:')
        print("Sam's Casino Version 1.1")
        random(self.cards)
        print(self.cards)

        self.deal(self)
        print(self.hand1)
        print(self.hand2)
        input('self.startup completed - ')

    def trick(self):
        self.points1_add = input('Points1_add? - ')
        self.points2_add = input('Points2_add? - ')
        self.points1 += self.points1_add
        self.points2 += self.pointd2_add
        input('trick test1 - ')

    def turn(self):
        startup(self)
        while self.points1 < 21 and self.points2 < 21:
            print('turn test - ')
            trick(self)

Key = input('Game()_run? - ')
if Key == 'y':
    Game().run()
elif Key == 'n':
    print('closing')
    input('ctest')
else:
    print('invalid input')
    input('')
```

Comment: What and where exactly is the problem?

Comment: What error message are you seeing when you attempt to run your program?

Comment: You are calling Game().run() but where are you defining that method? At the very least you will get "AttributeError: Game has not attribute run'

Answer (score 0):

If you dont' get any errors, then you need to check your work environment.  I clearly get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 60, in <module>
    Game().run()
  File "so.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.startup(self)
TypeError: startup() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This call is redundant:

```
    self.startup(self)
```

`self` is the implicit first argument to any instance method: the call object becomes that first parameter.  Simply call it as

```
    self.startup()
```

That will get you past the *first* structural problem.

---

I strongly recommend that you drop back and test your code in small pieces.  You've written over 50 lines of code without testing your structure.  Before you fill in so many details, test your connectivity.  Add a few lines at a time, testing each addition.  I've fixed three such errors now, and still getting errors.